# Removing prefix from figure captions in LaTeX

Tags: latex, tex, captions

I'd like to make my own caption inside `\caption{}` in figures of LaTeX. How can I turn off the "Figure " prefix from the captions that appear?

Answer (score 63):

First use the `caption` package and then use the command `\caption*` in this way

```
\usepackage{caption}
...
\caption*{some text}
```

instead of `\caption{some text}`

Logic is the same in avoiding numbering of sections and subsections and many other objects

```
\subsection*{Name of unnumbered subsection}
```

Comment: This does not work in a figure environment for the Beamer class at least. Actually none of these options work in Beamer as far as I can tell.

Comment: For beamer: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/82456/how-to-remove-figure-caption-prefix-figure-in-beamer

Comment: For me it works fine with beamer. According to the package's documentation beamer support was added in version 3.1 in 2007.

Answer (score 27):

You can use the `caption` package and do this:

```
\usepackage[labelformat=empty]{caption}
```

Comment: oops, sorry should have taken that into account. I've updated my answer.

Comment: I want this to apply only to figures in one section though, not globally

Answer (score 13):

Instead of defining the caption style when loading the `caption` package, set it up afterwards:

```
\usepackage{caption}% http://ctan.org/pkg/caption
...
\captionsetup[figure]{labelformat=empty}%
```

These changes will now only pertain to `figure` environments.

Comment: Works like a charm for `subfloat` too. Nice!

Answer (score 9):

You can use

```
\captionsetup[figure]{labelformat=empty}
```

to turn the caption text off and then use

```
\captionsetup[figure]{labelformat=default}
```

to turn the caption text on again if you want it to be different in different sections.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use additional packages, here is a work-around to put a caption (text) below the figures:

```
\includegraphics[width=1\linewidth]{figurename}\\[1mm]
  {---your caption---}
```